# Heroku + Sinatra + Datamapper

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, datamapper

Im getting issues deploying my Sinatra + DataMapper app to Heroku. The app works locally but deploying it blows up.

Here's the error:

Integer id with explicit :serial option is deprecated, use Serial instead (./hello.rb:15)
/home/slugs/339253_c667ceb_65a5-45e31e8c-0236-4d03-96ec-a59bdabdf788/mnt/.gems/gems/dm-migrations-1.0.2/lib/dm-migrations/adapters/dm-postgres-adapter.rb:84:in `property_schema_hash': bad value for range (ArgumentError)

The code looks like this:

```
Class Post
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,    Integer, :serial => true
  property :title, String
end

Post.auto_migrate!
first_post = Post.new
first_post.title = "First!"
first_post.save
```

Is this a gem versioning issue, or am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, it turns out that taking the advice from the log and using Serial, instead of Integer, :serial => true, fixes it. But my question still stands, Why did this work locally, and not on Heroku's server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use another version of datamapper locally it seems.

Check your local version with: `gem list --local`

Also use Serial instead of Integer as proposed.

Comment: I did that and Im using 1.0.2 locally, but I cant seem to check it through the heroku console.

Comment: Check out the Heroku docs: http://docs.heroku.com/gems there you can specify what version to use/install

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
Class Post
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,    Serial
  property :title, String
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the same version of DM locally and on heroku?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure. I ran 'sudo gem install dm-core', and 'sudo gem install dm-migrations'. How do I see the version of each gem that's currently installed?

Comment: If I run this: heroku console gem list, I get this:NameError: undefined local variable or method `list' for #<Object:0x2aaedc0722a8 @heroku_console_output=[]>
 /home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:150
 /home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:150:in `call'
 :0
 /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'

Answer (score 0):

Did you do [Bundle Install](http://docs.heroku.com/bundler) and then commit your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock? if not heroku woudln't have known which gems you wanted to use so just used it's default system gems. I guess they didn't quite match and that's why it exploded.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know about bundler at first and was just using a .gem file. I'll take a look at Bundler, thanks!